# How to show SmartCapture form on CloudPage only if value from sendable DE is false

Tags: marketing-cloud

The sendable data extension has a boolean field, I'd like to show the SmartCapture form only if the value is false. When trying to Schedule/Publish the page, the preview doesn't load.

```
%%[

var @FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @Attended
set @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
set @LastName = AttributeValue("LastName")
set @EmailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @Attended = AttributeValue("Attended")

]%%

%%[IF [Attended] == false THEN]%%
<div data-type="slot" data-key="chy0asetrn"></div>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

I'm using this line to show text and it works as expected, is it possible to do the same with a content block?

```
%%=Iif(@Attended == true, "Thank you for attending","Sorry we missed you")=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to use variables for your `IF` statement and put strings in quotes.

```
%%[IF @Attended == “false” THEN]%%
<div data-type="slot" data-key="chy0asetrn"></div>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```